# How to update elasticsearch field type

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I need to update elasticsearch field type integer to long I tried the following way and it not works

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/testwork/_mapping/message?ignore_conflicts=true' -d '
{
    "message" : {
        "properties" : {
            "status" : {"type" : "long"}
        }
    }
}
'
```

When tried without ignore_conflicts parameter it getting error like

```
{"error":"MergeMappingException[Merge failed with failures {[mapper [status] of different type, current_type [integer], merged_type [long]]}]","status":400}
```

But not get error while using  ignore_conflicts parameter got the response like

```
{"acknowledged":true}
```

But the type not changed for status field. Please help me to do this

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is not possible to change the data type if you have data present.

You'll have to delete your index, create the mapping with the data type you want, and re-index your data.

---

To re-index you will need to export and re-import your data - there are some tools (scan&scroll and bulk API) to make this easier, see [reindexing your data](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/reindex.html).

An alternative is to create a new index and then use [aliasing](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/index-aliases.html) - i.e. when doing an insert write to the latest index (could use an alias with a single index in it), but when doing a query, read from an alias that includes all relevant indexes (new and old versions of the index).

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. How can i back up the existing data? so i can restore the back up data after re indexing the collection.